# MS SQL server update takes way too long

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a "update" statement including a few inner joins. I run it on 400K rows and it takes about 11 minutes to execute which is way too long. I run the same statement on Access db and it takes 2 minutes. Is  there any way that I can increase the speed?

```
UPDATE AA 
SET 
AA.Status_Flag = mapper.Status_Flag, 
AA.Review_Required_Flag = mapper.Review_Required_Flag, 
AA.Exemption = mapper.CF_BB_Exemption, AA.Bloomberg_Flag = 'True',
AA.Bloomberg_Classification = mapper.LOGIC_IND 
FROM (AA INNER JOIN  
(SELECT * FROM tbl_BBG_Mapping inner join tbl_BBG_Out ON[tbl_BBG_Out].LOGIC_IND = tbl_BBG_Mapping.Status ) 
AS mapper ON AA.CUSIP = mapper.ID_CUSIP) 
INNER JOIN tbl_SAG_Diff ON
(AA.MSD_ID = tbl_SAG_Diff.MSD_ID) AND(AA.PRODUCT_ID = tbl_SAG_Diff.PRODUCT_ID)
WHERE AA.Added_Date = tbl_SAG_Diff.RUN_DATE;
```

Comment: Have you added indexes?

Comment: Have you consider to simplify your update query?

Comment: This update can not be simplified more than this.
I haven't tried indexes. How can I do that?

Comment: can you share your execution plan

Comment: Convert to select and type ctrl + m and run. This will give you the execution plan.

Comment: If you're unsure on how to add indexes, then I fear for your chances on resolving this issue. The issue could be anything. Without knowing the tables in question, the indexes, statistics and everything else, it could be anything. For instance, is it running in parallel? If so is it blocking itself? What isolation mode are you using? Is another process blocking? Way way too many variables here to provide a meaningful answer. Sure someone may 'chance' on one, but it'll be luck more than judgement if they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, **do not** use parentheses around your `join`s without documenting **why** you are doing that. It can have a significant impact on how the query runs, and if you don't know why you are doing it, don't do it at all. It is the equivalent of using query hints to force join order.

[Forcing Join Order Without Hints - Erik Darling](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/forcing-join-order-without-hints/)

Share your table schema, tables sizes, share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Without knowing your table schema and related DDL, or seeing an execution plan...

```
update AA set 
     AA.Status_Flag              = mapper.Status_Flag
   , AA.Review_Required_Flag     = mapper.Review_Required_Flag
   , AA.Exemption                = mapper.CF_BB_Exemption
   , AA.Bloomberg_Flag           = 'True'
   , AA.Bloomberg_Classification = bbgOut.LOGIC_IND
from AA
  inner join tbl_SAG_Diff as sd
     on AA.MSD_ID     = sd.MSD_ID 
    and AA.PRODUCT_ID = sd.PRODUCT_ID
    /* moved this from the where to the join */
    and AA.Added_Date = sd.RUN_DATE 

    /* join the tables instead of this query, update aliases as needed in `set` */
    /* inner join ( 
     select *
     from tbl_BBG_Mapping
      inner join tbl_BBG_Out 
        on [tbl_BBG_Out].LOGIC_IND = tbl_BBG_Mapping.status
     ) as mapper 
         on AA.CUSIP = mapper.ID_CUSIP
    */
  inner join tbl_BBG_Mapping as mapper
     on AA.CUSIP = mapper.ID_CUSIP
  inner join tbl_BBG_Out as bbgOut
     on mapper.status = bbgOut.LOGIC_IND
```

Comment: Thanks SqlZim. The mapper that I was using points to columns from both tables tbl_BBG_Mapping and tbl_BBG_Out. The one you provided , only points to tbl_BBG_Mapping.

Comment: How can I generate the execution plan?

Comment: @Navid Yes, the two tables have different aliases in my version, as I note you would need to update the aliases as needed in your `set`. I included both tables individually, notice alias `bbgOut` for setting `AA.Bloomberg_Classification`

Comment: @Navid Ctrl + L will show you an estimated execution plan, Ctrl + M will generate an actual execution plan after the query is executed in SSMS

Comment: I tried your script and it took longer.
Here is the execute plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJBPQcyKe

Comment: @Navid  Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: @Navid How many rows are in `tbl_BBG_Out` ? Can you add an index on it? `create index ix_tbl_bbg_out on dbo.tbl_bbg_out (id_cusip,volcker_rule_cvrd_fd_logic_ind)`

Comment: There are 5 million ish. I will try to add the index. Is that one time time only?

Comment: You only have to create the index once and then it will be managed by SQL Server.

Comment: I got this warning after running the index statement:

Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'ix_tbl_bbg_out' has maximum length of 1020 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

Comment: Try `create index ix_tbl_bbg_out on dbo.tbl_bbg_out (id_cusip) 
include (volcker_rule_cvrd_fd_logic_ind)` instead.

Comment: Wow! I am surprized! after I added the index the update runs in 2 seconds!!

Comment: I appreciate your time. You were of a great help